# Can I say "I am sorry?" when I can't hear something?

Tags: usage, spoken-english

As far as I know, we can say these when we can't hear something somebody said properly: "Excuse me?", "Sorry?" and "Pardon?".

What about **"I am sorry?"**? Can I also say "I am sorry?" instead of "Sorry?"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can. In fact, when *sorry* is used like that (to let the person you're speaking with know that you didn't hear properly what they said), it's really just a short version of *I'm sorry*. Here's a simple example:

> — I and my wife are going to Paris next month. Will you come with us?
>   — **I'm sorry.** What did you say? I didn't hear you well. Could you repeat that?

Comment: Thanks. Your example is different than what I mean though. Can I say merely say "I am sorry?" without using any other sentences when I want the speaker to repeat?

Comment: The answer to that is a resounding yes. You just have to say it with an appropriate intonation to indicate that you want the person you're talking with to repeat what they just said.

Comment: @FireandIce: Yes you can. I'd personally follow up with an elaboration (I find that "I'm sorry?" comes across as ambiguous between being offended and not having understood) but that's a matter of style. You don't need to elaborate further for your message to be understood, as long as it's inflected as a question rather than a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, but I can tell you from experience that the result of "(I'm) sorry" is not guaranteed. Why? Consider the following:

> 1. Sorry? Will you repeat, please? I did not get it.
> 2. Sorry? I understand the words, but I do not get the meaning. Will you please say the same thing with different words?
> 3. Sorry? Who the hell told you that?

So, the same "Sorry" in the same situation can mean several things, and the answers are definitely different for each meaning.

---

Bottom line: the "(I'm) sorry" part is perfectly fine to be used. It just needs some additional clarification, to be sure that you get what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's regional but I would never say "I am sorry" and I'm not sure I've ever heard someone else say it.

I would just say "sorry" or maybe "sorry, what (did you say)?"

I've heard people same "I'm sorry" but it sounds a bit formal/posh.

Comment: Hi @lewkir, I suggest you take a tour of the site first before posting an answer: https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour (Welcome to ELL!)